# Расширение Google Chrome, не работает replace

Tags: javascript, html, json

Пишу расширение для Google Chrome, и возникла проблема. Суть в том, что расширение должно заменять в выделенном тексте слово "ты" на "вы". Заменённый вариант можно увидеть через ярлык приложения.
Проблема в том, что "replace" не работает.
То есть, когда я выделил "ты", то "вы" не выводится.

core.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function(selection) {
    var selectedText = selection;
    var result = "";
    if (selectedText != ""){
        selectedText = selectedText.replace(/ты/g, "вы");  //Проблема
        result = selectedText;
    } else result = "Выделите текст!"
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result;
});
});
```

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="core.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "sample",
    "description": "A sample",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": { 
        "128": "128.png" 
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "main.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Через консоль проверял, вроде всё нормально отрабатывает помимо строки "document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я забыл `selectedText` сделать строкой. Вот исправленный вариант:

```
selectedText = selectedText.toString().replace(/ты/g, "вы");
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/511997)

Comment: @AlexSazonov это и есть ответ. Других ответов к вопросу нет.

Comment: @AlexSazonov "Вы сможете принять свой ответ завтра"